# In vscode, how to have multiple flutter targets in one launch.json?

Tags: flutter, vscode-debugger

I recently added

```
        {
            "name": "Flutter Web",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["-d", "chrome","--web-port", "9000", "--web-enable-expression-evaluation"],
        },
```

to my launch.json, since I need to specify a port for my flutter web debugging. But not, I'm finding it hard to switch back to ios or android. Vscode only wants to debug what is in the launch.json. Any suggestions on how to add android/ios debug configurations to the launch.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can add new configura and switch it in Run.

Comment: thank you for responding. do you know how to set one of these targets to ios and one to android? ideally, I'd like to be able to switch between the web/ios/android.

Comment: @foobar8675 1.select device on VSCode.It's in the bottom right corner.
2.VSCode -> View -> Command Palette -> Flutter: select device.
3. configura add args “-d xxxx"

Comment: Thank you VillainLin!

Comment: So is there no way to add a different device to the Build & Run configuration? Can you only click the device in the bottom-right of VS Code to change the target?